# opencart google sitemap vqmod error

Tags: opencart, xml-sitemap

I am trying to submit a google sitemap in the google webmaster tools but running into errors. In admin I clicked on the extensions >> product feeds and enabled google sitemaps options. It provided me the link for sitemap but when I submit the link to google webmaster tools it doesn't like it and comes back with following error:

```
Unsupported file format
Your Sitemap does not appear to be in a supported format. Please ensure it meets our Sitemap guidelines and resubmit.
```

here is the URL that I am using:
http://www.techcertsolutions.com/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap

error:
When I click on the sitemap link from google webmaster tools I see following message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: limit in /home7/jardinf1/public_html/techcertsolutions/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_catalog_product.php on line 440
```

I did check the `.htaccess` file and do see following entry in the file:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
```

so I'm not sure what is really happening here. I also deleted everything from `vqcache` and tried again but no luck. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Obviously you are using some vQmod extensions, check what extension is modifying catalog/model/catalog/product.php There is a conflict somewhere - namely 'limit' is missing but needed.

Answer (score 0):

One of your vQmod's is editing the `/catalog/model/catalog/product.php` file and for whatever reason is not setting the `limit` for the query, or the google sitemap code isn't setting the limit and should be

Answer (score -1):

If somebody has an issue like this still, there is a solution:

look for the file

```
/catalog/controller/feed/google_sitemap.php. Open it and edit it, then just replace where it says"$products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts(array('filter_category_id' => $result['category_id']));"
```

for

```
$total_ = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts();
                $data = array('start' => 0, 'limit' => $total_);
$products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts(array('filter_category_id' => $result['category_id'], 'start' => 0, 'limit' => $total_));
```